# FireBreath passing values from one function to another and using that functions in JavaScript

Tags: c++, visual-c++, plugins, firebreath

How can i pass `ptx` and `pty` from `TestPluginAPI::ClickSemulationMove` 
 to `TestPluginAPI::ClickSemulationClick(int ptx, int pty)`.
 The thing is that i must use this 2 functions in JavaScript and therefore can't simply expose it from one to another.

```
FB::variant TestPluginAPI::ClickSemulationClick(int ptx, int pty)
{

ShowCursor(true);
MouseLeft();
MouseReturn(ptx, pty);
ShowCursor(true);
return 0;
}

FB::variant TestPluginAPI::ClickSemulationMove(int ptx, int pty)
{
POINT pt;
MouseMove(-325, 605);
GetCursorPos(&pt);
ptx = pt.x;
pty = pt.y;
return 0;
}
```

As i get it i need to use JSObjectPtr or FB::VariantList, but i'm bit of confused without any sample. Can anyone show me the simple code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [JSAPI docs](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Supported+JSAPI+types)? All the information is there.

To return an array (will be a javascript array) with two values, you can just do:

```
return FB::variant_list_of(pt.x)(pt.y);
```

Then in javascript you could call the other method like:

```
var res = plugin().ClickSemulationMove(); // Assuming you don't actually need args here
plugin().ClickSemulationClick(res[0], res[1]);
```

You could also pass the array in directly, in which case you could do something like this in C++:

```
FB::variant TestPluginAPI::ClickSemulationClick(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    ShowCursor(true);
    MouseLeft();
    MouseReturn(arr[0], arr[1]);
    ShowCursor(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Seriously, there are example of all of these things in the [FBTestPlugin example](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/tree/master/examples/FBTestPlugin) in the FireBreath code base; you should spend some time in there. Most of the questions I see you asking could be quickly discovered for yourself from reading through that code and then you'd understand it better.

Comment: You helped me again, thx taxilian.
Just had no time when i struck on this, that's why drop it here.

Comment: And yes, i didn't read those JSAPI docs, don't know why, but I will.